# What is the current through the resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-measurement, current-source, network

[image]

In the figure we are supposed to find the current in 8ohm resistor. So by using simple KVL rule I was able to figure it out to be -1.25A.

But in the second approach
[image]

When I calculated current in 8 ohm resistor, it turned out to be 5.25A.
So which answer should I report?
And why is there difference in answer I changed the approach?

Comment: How can we know where you went wrong if you don't show your work?

Comment: The answer is correct as it is self evident that the potential difference across the branch 32V and 8ohm resistor is 42 volts, and also in the second case it is 42 volts across 8ohm resistor. Also across 24ohm and 14 ohm resistor current was found to be 1.75A and 3A respectively, in both the methods.

Comment: The voltage "appears" across the resistor. Not the current. The current can only flow through that resistor. Also, why do you think that these currents should be equal?

Comment: Because it's the same resistor and we have only transformed voltage source to current source, so there should not be any difference in current in the resistor.

Comment: No, this cannot be true. Only for the "rest" of the circuit ( without E1 and 8R ) currents and voltages will stay the same. Take a look here https://tinyurl.com/2234oa3c  As you can see only the right part of a circuit sees the same voltages and currents.

Comment: The link is not working, saying that I am blocked.

Comment: The full link to the online simulator is too long. But never mind. As I said only the right part of a circuit will see unchanged voltages and currents. But this is not true for elements that were transformed. Besides, you proved it to yourself by doing this exercise.

Comment: @Preet Just transform the right side to get a voltage and source resistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I1 and r1 are transformations of E1 and R1. R1 is not r1.  Only the terminal characteristics are the same. The R1 current in the second figure is shown by the red arrow below

[image]

Comment: Okay understood! But then what is the significance of current in r1 which was coming out to be 5.25A.

Comment: The current in r1 is the resistor current for the Norton equivalent.  It has no special significance

Answer (score 3):

The second circuit uses a source transformation to create an equivalent source and resistor output at the terminals. The answers should be different, as it changes the source and resistor.The transformation makes it so that when looking through the terminals, everything will appear the same for the rest of the circuit. I think the idea here is to use the source transformation to solve the right side of the circuit, and then you can go back and solve the original circuit without doing much analysis. Refer to the pictures to see terminals.
[image]

[image]